# JSON-Schema oneOf for option under root area

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to get the "oneof" to allow for options in root items but can't find an example and what I try gives an error.
I can get it to work if it is under another item but not under the root {'s

Example - a Job Payment that has required fields (jobNum, payee, amount, type, ) and an option for the payment type (checkInfo or dollarAmt). I know this could be done other ways, but I need this method for a more complex schema.

```
{
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "checkInfo": {
        "number": "386"
    }
}
{
    "JobNum": "x216",
    "Payee": "John Doe",
    "type" : "Cash",    
    "amount" : "112.25",
    "cashInfo" : {
        "dollarAmt" : "112",
        "coinAmt" : "0.25"
    }   
}
```

The following gives me this error -  "Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'oneOf'. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got StartArray"

```
{
    "description": "Job Payment",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "jobNum", "payee", "amount", "type"],
    "properties": {
        "jobNum": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "payee": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "amount": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {"enum": [ "check", "cash" ]
        },
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCash" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCheck" }
        ]
    },
    "definitions": {
        "ptCash": {
            "properties": {
                "checkInfo": {
                    "number": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [ "checkInfo" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "ptCheck": {
            "properties": {
                "dollarAmt": { 
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "coinAmt": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [ "dollarAmt", "coinAmt" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: I've seen several attempts and answering this question but when actually put into an online validator that conforms with the standards there are multiple errors. The validator I'm using is:
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `oneOf` should be placed in prope
2. Have to re-write rule for both `ptCash` and `ptCheck` by using `type: object`

Following schema should work with `ptCheck`:

```
{
    "description": "Job Payment",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "jobNum", "payee", "amount", "type"],
    "properties": {
        "jobNum": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "payee": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "amount": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {"enum": [ "check", "cash" ]
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCash" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCheck" }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "ptCash": {
            "properties": {
                "checkInfo": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["number"],
                    "properties": {
                        "number": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [ "checkInfo" ]
        },
        "ptCheck": {
            "properties": {
                "cashInfo": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "dollarAmt": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "coinAmt": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["dollarAmt", "coinAmt"]
                }
            },
             "required": ["cashInfo"]
        }
    }
}
```

Provide some example as below:

```
import jsonschema
import simplejson as json

schema_filename = '47926398.json'
with open(schema_filename, 'r') as f:
    schema_data = f.read()
schema = json.loads(schema_data)

# validate with checkInfo
json_obj = {
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "checkInfo": {
        "number": "386"
    }
}
jsonschema.validate(json_obj, schema)


# invalidate
json_obj = {
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "checkInfox": {
        "number": "386"
    }
}
jsonschema.validate(json_obj, schema)


# validate with cashInfo
json_obj = {
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "cashInfo": {
        "dollarAmt": "400",
        "coinAmt": "30"
    }
}
jsonschema.validate(json_obj, schema)

# invalidate with cashInfo
json_obj = {
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "cashInfox": {
        "dollarAmt": "400",
        "coinAmt": "30"
    }
}
jsonschema.validate(json_obj, schema)

# invalidate with cashInfo.dollarAmtx
json_obj = {
    "jobNum": "x216",
    "payee": "John Doe",
    "type": "check",
    "amount": "112.25",
    "cashInfo": {
        "dollarAmtx": "400",
        "coinAmt": "30"
    }
}
jsonschema.validate(json_obj, schema)
```

Comment: Oh, it is outside of the properties.  I didn't think of it like that.

Comment: Almost, but why does it still validate if you don't have either checkInfo or cashInfo, I though the oneOf required you to have one of them?

Comment: @runfastman: I provide full schema and some examples, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was just missing the "required": ["cashInfo"] on the second item, that was making it match to nothing.  (sorry for the long delay, Christmas Stuff)

Comment: Your schema does not validate:


Message:
    JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'.
Schema path:
    #/oneOf

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: cashInfo.
Schema path:
    #/definitions/ptCheck/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: checkInfo.
Schema path:
    #/definitions/ptCash/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: jobNum, payee, amount, type.
Schema path:
    #/required

Answer (score 3):

There are a a few issues with your schema. I fixed it for you below. I won't explain all the changes I made because I think it is mostly pretty clear by reading the schema. If you want more detail on anything, just ask and I'll update the answer with more details.

The `oneOf` keyword can only appear in a schema. The `properties` keyword is an object whose values are schemas. When you put "oneOf" directly under `properties`, it's not interpreted as a keyword, it's interpreted as a property called "oneOf". The validator then complains because the value of property "oneOf" is expected to be a schema, not an array of schemas like the `oneOf` keyword.

Your use of `additionalProperties` doesn't work. This keyword doesn't work the way people often assume that it does. JSON Schema keywords are not aware of any state outside of the schema they are in. Let's look at the "ptCheck" branch of your `oneOf` first. This describes the property "number", says it is required and that there may be no keywords other than "number".  Then your top level defines a the properties "jobNum", "payee", "amount", and "type", requires them all and allows no other properties. These two things can never be true at the same time. Even though your schema is valid, there is no JSON value that can ever be valid against this schema. That's why I moved the definitions of "checkInfo" and "cashInfo" to the top level and only put the `required` part in `oneOf`. The only downside to this approach is that you can pass both a "checkInfo" and a "cachInfo" object and it will validate. The extraneous property gets ignored. There are ways around this, but they are problematic enough that I don't advise using them.

I always advise people not to use `"additionalProperties": false` and to ignore unknown properties instead. The reason is that JSON Schema is a constraint system.  Any valid JSON is valid against the empty schema (`{}`) and each keyword in the schema adds some constraint. This is a different approach to what people are used to when defining classes. An empty class describes nothing and valid values are added. We use `"additionalProperties": false` to get JSON Schema to behave more like defining a class, but trying to get JSON Schema to behave like something it isn't causes challenges like the one you see here.

---

```
{
  "description": "Job Payment",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["jobNum", "payee", "amount", "type"],
  "properties": {
    "jobNum": { "type": "string" },
    "payee": { "type": "string" },
    "amount": { "type": "string" },
    "type": { "enum": ["check", "cash"] },
    "checkInfo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "number": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["number"]
    },
    "cashInfo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "dollarAmt": { "type": "string" },
        "coinAmt": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["dollarAmt", "coinAmt"]
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCash" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/ptCheck" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "ptCheck": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": ["check"] }
      },
      "required": ["checkInfo"]
    },
    "ptCash": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": ["cash"] }
      },
      "required": ["cashInfo"]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: I just checked your schema against the site. Did not validate.
Results:
 Found 4 error(s)

Message:
    JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'.
Schema path:
    #/oneOf

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: checkInfo.
Schema path:
    #/definitions/ptCheck/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: cashInfo.
Schema path:
    #/definitions/ptCash/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: jobNum, payee, amount, type.
Schema path:
    #/required

Comment: What doesn't validate? Which site? If you are using the second example given in the question. You might notice that it uses the wrong capitalization in a few places and thus should not validate. When you fix those errors, the example validates correctly.

Comment: I put the site link above in a comment to the original question. I saw only two replies with code, counting yours, and I ran them both through the same validator. I can see how that independent comment might have been missed so here is the link again:
 jsonschemavalidator.net 
Put your code in that and see the results. I was really hoping one of the answers given would validate because I have the same issue as the OP.

Comment: I think you're confused about the error messaging. You seem to be under the impression that those errors are telling you that the schema is invalid. The errors are saying that the instance being validated (`{ }`) is invalid. Put a valid instance in the box on the right and the errors will go away.

Comment: Good to know! I'll check that out. I'd be happy to be wrong on this as I would really like a schema that matches the question of the OP on many points.

Comment: I just ran your schema against both examples from the OP. The first validates without issue. The second does not.